# C dynamic allocating memory for array within a struct

Tags: c, arrays, dynamic-data

First I defined this struct:

```
typedef struct{
    int **_data;
    int _num_of_lines;
    int *_lines_len;
} Lines;
```

my goal is to receive `_num_of_lines` as input from user.
which will be used to define number of line of the 2D array `data`
whereas the array `_lines_len` repreasants length of each line in `data`

I'm trying to malloc memory for `_lines_len`, but I always get back that the size of the array is 2, and I don't understand why...

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    Lines linesStruct;
    printf("enter num of lines:\n ");
    scanf("%d",&linesStruct._num_of_lines);
    printf("Num of lines is = %d \n", linesStruct._num_of_lines);

    linesStruct._lines_len = (int*) malloc(linesStruct._num_of_lines * sizeof(int));
    int len = (int) ((sizeof(linesStruct._lines_len))/(sizeof(int)));
    printf("number of lines len = %d \n", len);
```

Comment: `sizeof` on a pointer returns the size of the pointer, not the buffer that follows it.

Comment: `sizeof(linesStruct._lines_len)` returns the size of memory for an `int *`, not the length of your array.

Comment: hmmm I don't quite get it then, how do I figure out what is the length of the array after the allocation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sizeof(linesStruct._lines_len)` return the size of the *pointer* (i.e. two words).  There's really no way to statically determine the array size at compile time.  But you've got that stored in `_num_of_lines` anyway.

Answer (score 0):

**linesStruct._num_of_lines** already tells you the array size.

Variable **len** will always have the value of 1, because the size of integer pointer is the same as integer.

```
int len = (int) ((sizeof(linesStruct._lines_len))/(sizeof(int)));
```

Plus, [You don't cast the malloc() result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc/605858#605858).